# In valid json, How to parse .txt and store tweets in CSV?

Tags: python, json, twitter

I have a txt file with json tweets like this, every tweet is between ["text": & "is_quote_status":] and date is at the end of the line, how to extract just the tweets and dates to a csv file?

I was finally able to crack this with 2 codes. Thanks to @mark, it took time to figure out but i did it.

to clean the json file.:

```
fin = open("sim.txt")
fout = open("output.txt", "w+")
delete_list = ['ObjectId(', 'NumberLong(','ISODate(', ')']
for line in fin:
    for word in delete_list:
        line = line.replace(word, "")
    fout.write(line)    
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

To extract tweets and dates to store them in .csv

```
import json
import csv
infile = open("output1.txt","r")
outfile=open("output4.csv","w")
json_s=infile.read()
writer=csv.writer(outfile)
for data in(json.loads(json_s)):
    x=data['text'].encode("utf-8")
    y=data['created_at_date'].encode("utf-8")
    writer.writerow([x,y])
infile.close()
outfile.close()
print 'DONE'
```

Sample .json string i had-

```
{
     "_id": "582f4fbd44b65941a0a81213",
     "contributors": null,
     "truncated": false,
     "text": "Tonight at 10 PM ET, 7 PM PT, on @FoxNews, a one hour special on me and my life by @HarveyLevinTMZ. Enjoy!",
     "is_quote_status": false,
     "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
     "id": "799660246788612100",
     "favorite_count": 15765,
     "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>",
     "retweeted": false,
     "coordinates": null,
     "entities": {
        "symbols": [],
        "user_mentions": [{
          "id": 1367531,
          "indices": [33, 41],
          "id_str": "1367531",
          "screen_name": "FoxNews",
          "name": "Fox News"
        }, {
          "id": 36098990,
          "indices": [83, 98],
          "id_str": "36098990",
          "screen_name": "HarveyLevinTMZ",
          "name": "Harvey Levin"
        }],
        "hashtags": [],
        "urls": []
      },
      "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
      "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
      "retweet_count": 5251,
      "id_str": "799660246788612100",
      "favorited": false,
     "user": {
        "id": 25073877,
        "id_str": "25073877"
      },
      "geo": null,
      "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
      "lang": "en",
      "created_at": "Fri Nov 18 17:07:14 +0000 2016",
      "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
      "place": null,
      "created_at_date": "2016-11-18T17:07:14Z"
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation and in particular [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You've shown no attempt to extract tweets from json using python. Give us your best attempt as a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- then we all will have something to work on together.

Comment: As a first step to solve the problem, you might check out python's built-in [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module for reading the data, and [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module for writing the result to a `csv` file.

Answer (score 0):

Please take note of json path and you must have a valid json in your text file.

**/path/to/json/file.json**

```
[{
        "_id": "dummyid1",
        "contributors": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "Dummy tweet 1",
        "is_quote_status": false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "id": "799660246788612100",
        "favorite_count": 15765,
        "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>",
        "retweeted": false,
        "coordinates": null,
        "entities": {
            "symbols": [],
            "user_mentions": [{
                "id": 1367531,
                "indices": [33, 41],
                "id_str": "1367531",
                "screen_name": "FoxNews",
                "name": "Fox News"
            }, {
                "id": 36098990,
                "indices": [83, 98],
                "id_str": "36098990",
                "screen_name": "HarveyLevinTMZ",
                "name": "Harvey Levin"
            }],
            "hashtags": [],
            "urls": []
        },
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "retweet_count": 5251,
        "id_str": "799660246788612100",
        "favorited": false,
        "user": {
            "id": 25073877,
            "id_str": "25073877"
        },
        "geo": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "lang": "en",
        "created_at": "Fri Nov 18 17:07:14 +0000 2016",
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "place": null,
        "created_at_date": "2016-11-18T17:07:14Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "dummyid2",
        "contributors": null,
        "truncated": false,
        "text": "Dummy tweet 2",
        "is_quote_status": false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "id": "799660246788612100",
        "favorite_count": 15765,
        "source": "<a href=\"http://twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter Web Client</a>",
        "retweeted": false,
        "coordinates": null,
        "entities": {
            "symbols": [],
            "user_mentions": [{
                "id": 1367531,
                "indices": [33, 41],
                "id_str": "1367531",
                "screen_name": "FoxNews",
                "name": "Fox News"
            }, {
                "id": 36098990,
                "indices": [83, 98],
                "id_str": "36098990",
                "screen_name": "HarveyLevinTMZ",
                "name": "Harvey Levin"
            }],
            "hashtags": [],
            "urls": []
        },
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "retweet_count": 5251,
        "id_str": "799660246788612100",
        "favorited": false,
        "user": {
            "id": 25073877,
            "id_str": "25073877"
        },
        "geo": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "lang": "en",
        "created_at": "Fri Nov 18 17:07:14 +0000 2016",
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "place": null,
        "created_at_date": "2016-11-18T17:07:14Z"
    }
]
```

**script.py**

```
import json

with open('/path/to/json/file.json', 'r') as f:
    json_string = f.read()

datas_from_json = json.loads(json_string) # json string now a iterable list

for data in datas_from_json:
    print(data['text'])

# outputs
# Dummy tweet 1
# Dummy tweet 2
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load' ---i am getting this error what to do?

Comment: every tweet is between ("text": & "is_quote_status":)can you tell me how to parse the txt file and save the tweet between these two tags?

Comment: about: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load' -- you have to import json

Comment: @sambuddu I have modified your sample json because you have provider us a non-valid json, I also modify the answer.

Comment: can you pls tell me how to parse the text and save the tweets to a csv?

Comment: your question is going deeper, you should update your main question or post another question. the example above will parse your "Valid" json file.

Answer (score 0):

This process can be made simple by using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/).

Consider you have a valid json file at `/path/to/input.json` or `/path/to/input.txt`, file extension doesn't matters as far as a valid json is present.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("path/to/input.txt")
df[["text", "created_at_date"]].to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: how to extract just the tweet and date and write them to .csv?

Comment: @sambuddu are you talking about the `text` field in the json string? Can you specify which are the fields you want to export to csv.

Comment: @sambuddu updated the answer, you can specify the fields you want to export as updated in the answer.